# How do I know where a pipeline is running because of schedule or trigger

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

In Azure DevOps YAML, I can specify that a pipeline runs based on a schedule or a trigger:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - develop

schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily 9pm
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
```

Within the YAML, how do I detect whether the pipeline is running due to the schedule rather than the trigger? Is there a variable I can use in a condition? The reason I want this is that I'd like to schedule an overnight deployment and then run end to end tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a variable I can use in a condition?

Of course, yes. We provide one [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables) names `Build.Reason` can let you know the trigger type of current pipeline.

Just configure the condition like below:

```
 - bash: |
    echo "run test"
   condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule') ## run this task when the pipeline is triggered due to schedule.
```